# Running command on start up

Tags: 12.10, touchpad

I have a series of 'sudo' commands that I have to run on terminal everytime I boot up my system so that my touchpad is use-able. Is there some file that I can configure so that these commands run immediately when I boot up without me having to manually input them?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Put the commands *without* `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local`. The commands you put in there will be run as root during boot.

Also make sure to read the comment in the file present there already, which basically says you need to make sure you put all new lines *above* the `exit 0` line.